# HybridAuth hide additional information form for twitter

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm trying to integrate [hybridauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module for social login. Its working fine for Facebook.

But for twitter, after successful sign in, its asking E-mail, first name, last name & gender details.

If I uncheck required information, I won't get email to create user in back-end.

How can we do set up in twitter side to get these details?

Or

Is there any way to get these required informations with out showing the form?

My intention to successfully login into Drupal site after sign in using twitter, with out asking any addition informations.

***After sign in I'm getting below form (Want to hide this form):***

[image]

***Drupal back end setting (If i hide, above form wont come but can't get email ID and other details):***

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it prompts for that information is the Twitter API doesn't provide it; you can't [retrieve user emails](https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-email-is-using-twitter-api-on-callback-page-using-php/404) through the API; it only provides a single field for a user's real name (thus the prompt for the last name); and it doesn't collect information on a user's gender.